# Get node value with HTML in XML via PHP

Tags: php, html, xml

My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SHOP>
  <SHOPITEM>
    <ITEM_ID>8</ITEM_ID>
    <PRODUCT>Body EMMER W 12</PRODUCT>
    <DESCRIPTION>
      <p>Test 1
        <br />Good
        <br />Big
        <br />Long
        <br />Works
      </p>
    </DESCRIPTION>
  </SHOPITEM>
</SHOP>
```

**SEE:** node `DESCRIPTION` contains HTML content, these are not another nodes.

Then in PHP I open XML file:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("file1.xml");
foreach($xml->children() as $data) {
  ...
}
```

Then I want to save some values, so:

```
$product = array(
  "id" => (string) $data->ITEM_ID,
  "item_name" => (string) $data->PRODUCT,
  "description" => (string) $data->DESCRIPTION
);
```

But when I print these to the HTML table, description is empty. Reason is, that PHP recognize that `<p>` element like another node, so there will be no text/value. What should I do?

Comment: Into XML description should be save with function 'htmlspecialchars'

Comment: I can't edit XMLs and I'm not the one who creates these files. I just have to process them. @anttiviljami found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your XML file is actually a mix of HTML and XML, which is a bit messy. The best thing to do here would be to fix this by wrapping the HTML in `<![CDATA[""]]>` (character data) tags which would enable you to use exactly the PHP script you're trying to use.

So instead of

```
<DESCRIPTION>
  <p>Test 1
    <br />Good
    <br />Big
    <br />Long
    <br />Works
  </p>
</DESCRIPTION>
```

You should use

```
<DESCRIPTION>
  <![CDATA[
    <p>Test 1
      <br />Good
      <br />Big
      <br />Long
      <br />Works
    </p>
  ]]>
</DESCRIPTION>
```

If editing the xml file isn't an option, you can just to stringify the children with [`SimpleXMLElement::asXML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php) like this:

```
$product = array(
  //...
  "description" => (string) $data->DESCRIPTION->asXML(),
);
```

EDIT:

Please note that using the latter method, `$data->DESCRIPTION->asXML()` will include the wrapping `<DESCRIPTION>` tabs.

Comment: You are great! I forgot to say, that I can't edit XMLs, but you answered also to that problem. Thanks a lot!